# Installed certificate, but can't see it in the code signing drop down in xcode?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I installed the certification for code signing in my keychain as per the instructions, but in xcode I can't see the certification name in the drop down in the Project Info, Build section.

How do I make xcode find it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a difference between certificates and provisioning profiles. You have to generate a provisioning profile first, which I think you can now do right in the Organizer as you can see in WrightsCS's screenshot. Just press the Refresh button.

You MAY have to do something on the website too, I'm not sure because I started before the Organizer had that functionality. But it seems like the key problem is you're expecting the certificate to be a provisioning profile, which it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Open up Xcode, then to Organizer *(Window -> Organizer)*. From your desktop, take the certificate and drop it onto Organizer, and you should see the list of certificates you have successfully installed.
[image]. You should now be able to select the profile in your drop-down menu.

*Note: All of the certificates you see on this screen will appear in your drop-down.*

Comment: i see 1 entry in developer profile but not in provisioning profile...why is that? do I have to login?